# Output a list of files that match a string

Tags: ubuntu, shell, scripting

I'm trying to write a script that will search a directory for specific .deb files to install and output a numbered list of available .deb files in that said directory.

Ex. Search root folder for all file names that contain "install.deb" and output them in a list ex. 1. newinstall.deb 2. oldinstall.deb 3. install.deb etc.

Comment: It's two commands, `ls` and `nl`. But as you haven't actually asked a question I'm not sure what the issue is

Comment: Which part of this is it you're having issues with?

Answer (score 0):

`find` can be used to find regular files whose name ends in `.deb` and `awk` (`mawk` or `gawk` implementations at least, the ones found as `awk` on Ubuntu systems) can be used to do the numbering and formatting. We can throw in a call to `sort` to get a sorted list. As always with file paths, we use NUL-delimited records as the interchange format as newline is as valid a character as any in a file path, hence the `-print0`, `-z` (GNU extensions) and `RS='\0'`:

```
LC_ALL=C find -H "$root_folder" -name '*.deb' -type f -print0 |
  sort -z |
  awk -v RS='\0' '{printf "%3d. %s\n", NR, $0}'
```

Instead of `awk`, you could use `perl` which would make it portable to systems where `awk` doesn't support NUL as the record separator:

```
perl -0lne 'printf "%3d. %s\n", $., $_'
```

To exclude hidden ones, insert a `-name '.?*' -prune -o` after `"$root_folder"`. An alternative, if you're using the zsh shell is to use its globs which are sorted and exclude hidden files by default, and don't have the same issues as GNU `find` when filenames are not valid text in the locale:

```
n=0
for f ( $root_folder/**/*.deb(N.) ) printf '%3d. %s\n' ++n $f
```

Contrary to `find`, it also won't break if `$root_folder` starts with `-` or is `!`/`(`...